# Django Dynamic Forms

Tags: django, forms, dynamic

I am using [James Bennetts code](http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2008/nov/09/dynamic-forms/) to create a dynamic form. I have everything working but want to save the data to a database. Has anyone got any code which does this or could show me what the best way to do this would be e.g. how the model should be set up etc?

Comment: You'll have to show us some code to help you - like are you using forms.Form or forms.ModelForm. For the most part though, with the former, you can define a save() method for the form and access data from cleaned_data.

Comment: the code I am using is copied directly from the James Bennett article (see line above).  It is using neither forms.form or forms.modelform, it is automatically generating form elements on the fly which I then want to add to the database

Answer (score 2):

Override the `save()` method on your form class:

```
def save(self):
    new_user = User.objects.create_user(username=self.cleaned_data['username'],
                                        email=self.cleaned_data['email'],
                                        password=self.cleaned_data['password1'])
    return new_user
```

(taken from James Bennett's blog at [Newforms, part 2](http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2007/nov/23/newforms/))

Comment: I don't have a object to override since it is different everytime and is generated on the fly

Comment: I take it then that your code is based on his version of `make_contact_form` that uses `type` to generate the class?

Comment: Yes thats correct.  I plan to expand on his code so that instead of hard coding which form elements are required, I will pull them in from a database table which is populated by a user